# 12.10 to 18.04 Backup has been saved as diff files, unable to reintregrate as a whole

Tags: grub2, 12.10, backup, data-recovery

I had 12.10 on my machine, I backed up onto an external hard drive, I was informed that the back up was complete. I installed 18.04 and then tried to reinstall my saved files. 'Backup failed' was the answer. I opened the files up on the external harddrive and they were saved as diff files, I searched and to assist was informed to type `sudo update-grub` then  `shutdown -r now` 
the machinie rebooted. I pressed <kbd>shift</kbd> (to access recovery mode) still no files showing however I was able to access the files better. When I extracted one of the hundreds of 'boxes' a small piece of file was available e.g saved video, one second of it. Then in another box another small bit of video. The files all seem to be there but it appears I cannot integrate them into the original ones. Here are some screenshots

[image: How to files look]

[image: How the files are unzipped]

[image]

Comment: Hello Help, and welcome to Ask Ubuntu. In order to increase that chances that somebody gives a good answer to your question, the first thing to do is ask a question; Further post the commands how you tried to backup.

Comment: Hi abu_bua I went into backup (Deja dup) clicked on the backup button, after I had clicked where the backup was stored. The commands I used sudo update-grub , then shutdown -r now, then shift and I was able to access the files a little more. I 'extracted to desktop' one of the many files.

Comment: sudo update grub

Comment: shutdown -r now